# A good translation of "bimah"

Tags: synagogue, translation

What is a good translation of the word "bimah" (as in both the "stage" generally and the "table" specifically in a synagogue whence the Torah is read) to use with a non-Jew?  Altar and stage both seem wrong and "platform" is too general.  It is likely that two words are needed.

Inspired by [this comment](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/22265/do-synagogues-have-a-chair-vacant-for-the-messiah#comment50783_22265).

Comment: Perhaps "Dais"?

Comment: @DoubleAA maybe.  It's certainly closer.  Want to submit as an answer?

Comment: Which sense of _bima_ are you referring to in the question? Gotta know that to know how to translate it.

Comment: @msh210 see edit

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman, specifically, I've heard _bima_ used to refer to the table the _Tora_ is put on, and to refer to the stage people stand on when reading the _Tora_ off of that table. Your edit doesn't clarify (for me) which of those you mean.

Comment: @msh210 I'm interested in a translation of both parts, actually.  Two translations makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Platform would be the literal translation, "Podium" or "Lectern" should do.

Comment: I think of a "podium" or "lectern" as a reading desk, but a "platform" would be the whole raised area (potentially much larger).

Comment: Lectern/podium implies something resembling what is often referred to as a Shtender.

Comment: Please see the updated question.