# Is there a Moses Seat in Synagogue?

Tags: synagogue, moshe-rabbeinu, standing-sitting

Is there a Moses seat in Synagogue? I know about the Chair of Elijah but I came to know there is also Moses Seat. Please confirm.

Comment: I have never heard of or seen that practice. The Chair of Elijah is documented [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22265/1569). The "Moses Seat" is discussed in [this answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/25811/1569).

Comment: http://www.yeshiva.org.il/wiki/index.php?title=%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%91%D7%A5:Throne.jpg possibly?

Comment: The question could be improved if you add a premise! What led you to think there would be such a thing?

Comment: I never heard of such a thing

Answer (score 5):

There used to be such a thing in ancient synagogues. This special chair was referred to in [Pesikta D'Rav Kahana 1:7](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Pesikta_D%27Rav_Kahanna.1.7?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> "וראש עגל לכסא מאחריו (מלכים א' י:יט), א"ר אחא כהדא קתדרא דמשה."

Translation: "And a rounded head on the back of the chair (Kings 1:10:19), said Rav Acha: "like the Chair of Moshe"."

As noted by [Cecil Roth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cecil_Roth) in his essay "The "Chair of Moses" and its survivals", Palestine Exploration Quarterly, 1949 (emphasis mine):

> "It was indeed pointed out some time ago that R. Aha...explained the Biblical description of Solomon's throne by saying that it was "like the *cathedra* of Moses"...**which would suggest that some specific object was in his mind**..."

L'havdil, it was also mentioned in the [NT](https://biblehub.com/matthew/23-2.htm):

> "The scribes and Pharisees sit in Moses’ seat."

Archeologists believe that they have found some of these chairs.

As Roth further wrote:

> "Recently, however, in the course of excavations of the Palestinian synagogues of the first centuries of the Christian era, there have been found some stone chairs of a distinctive nature which have been unhesitatingly identified with the actual "Chair of Moses": it is believed that they were reserved for the most distinguished of the elders of "Rulers of the Synagogue", who we know sat apart "with their faces to the congregation and their backs towards the Sanctuary" ([Tosefta Megillah 3:21](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Tosefta_Megillah_(Lieberman).3.21?vhe=The_Tosefta_according_to_to_codex_Vienna._Third_Augmented_Edition,_JTS_2001&lang=bi)). The first cathedra of this type, 94 centimetres in height, was unearthed against the south wall of the synagogue of [El Hammeh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tell_el-Hammeh) (the Baths of Tiberias) at the side of the Ark...and is carved out of a single block of white limestone:
>
> [image]
>
> the second was found at Chorazin (Kerazeh), and like the rest of the building is of basalt."

[image]

(Chorazin chair image taken from [here](http://www.antiquities.org.il/t/item.aspx?CurrentPageKey=1&shalemid=2717))

Roth himself continues on and explains why he believes these chairs cannot be the "Chair of Moses", and suggests that special chairs or tables - also discovered in ancient synagogues worldwide - that were used to hold Torah scrolls are the real "Chair of Moses".

Israel Renov, on the other hand, in his essay "[The Seat of Moses](https://www.jstor.org/stable/27924631?read-now=1&refreqid=excelsior%3Af9e5706ff65195e845e3b9b7d69421bf&seq=3#page_scan_tab_contents)", points out flaws in Roth's hypothesis. He then brings evidence that such chairs were in fact used by important community leaders, for example, [Shir Hashirim Rabbah 1:3](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shir_HaShirim_Rabbah.1.3.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> "...וּבֵית מִדְרָשׁוֹ שֶׁל רַבִּי אֱלִיעֶזֶר הָיָה עָשׂוּי כְּמִין רִיס, וְאֶבֶן אַחַת הָיְתָה שָׁם וְהָיְתָה מְיֻחֶדֶת לוֹ לִישִׁיבָה"

Translation: "...And the study hall of Rabbi Eliezer was built like a ris, and there was one stone there, and it was set aside for him [Rabbi Eliezer] to sit upon."

This "stone", according to Renov, was Rabbi Eliezer's stone chair.

Furthermore, in the Talmud ([Megillah 26b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Megillah.26b.11?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi)), there's mention of a kind of platform used for reading the Torah. It was called a "כורסייא". Renov argues that if Rav Acha was talking about such a thing, as Roth opined, he would surely have used the same term, and not referred to it with a completely different term "קתדרא דמשה".

For more info and other views, see [here](http://talmudandarchaelogy.blogspot.com/2018/08/blog-post.html), [here](https://segulamag.com/news/winepress-in-korazim/) and [here](https://www.ybz.org.il/_Uploads/dbsAttachedFiles/Article_72.4.pdf). In short, most scholars nowadays disagree with Roth and believe that these special stone seats were most likely the "Chair of Moses" mentioned in Tannaic and Amoraic-era sources.

Nowadays some synagogues have special chairs for rabbis, though generally not made of stone. Other synagogues set aside chairs for rabbis, but these chairs are the same as the rest of the congregation's. These seats are not referred to as "the Chair of Moses" or "the Seat of Moses" but simply as "the rabbi's place/chair/seat/bench".

Comment: Did you see https://www.yeshiva.org.il/wiki/index.php/%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%95%D7%98%D7%99%D7%9D כסא משה רבינו

Comment: @DoubleAA I noticed your earlier comment only after posting. Good find. Also, that chair looks a little more comfortable... :)

Comment: I'm out of my league here but it would be interesting if the tradition stuck around longer in the romaniote community

Comment: There is a parallel midrash here https://www.sefaria.org/Pesikta_D'Rav_Kahanna.1.7?lang=bi&p2=Esther_Rabbah.1.12&lang2=bi&p3=Matnot_Kehunah_on_Esther_Rabbah.1.12.22&lang3=bi that uses the term קדירתא דדרגיש, which the Matnot Kehuna describes as a pot-shaped (round) feature of a bed, which would fit the possuk's description of עגל. This leads me to believe that the text of the Pesikta is a typo, and it should read קדירתא דמטה.

Comment: @N.T. Yes, I know about that midrash. It's mentioned in the last essay I linked. He concludes the opposite, that the midrash in Esther is a typo.

Comment: I would say that the דדרושה in that midrash also should be דדרגשא, with part of the gimmel missing it turned into a vav. Even if there was such a thing as a כסא של משה, I assume it was not standardized. The one in the picture of that essay is not round at all. I don't see how the reference to a 'chair of Moshe" is useful. Referring to the headrest of a bed, OTOH, would be very useful.

Comment: @N.T. Not too many chairs were found, so it'd be hard to know whether or not most chairs were rounded in some sort of way. Furthermore, notice that the chairs that we do have are broken. The best-preserved one was linked by DoubleAA. That was not round, but then again, perhaps in the diaspora there were other chair models? In short, theories can go in many directions.

Comment: IMO I think a possibly metaphorical statement in the New Testament and one out of three parallel midrashim is not enough evidence to give this claim serious legs. Especially because the Chair of Eliyahu is not part of the standard synagogue, just part of the bris ceremony. It is also not standardized in any way. Lots of synagogues have special chairs for the rabbi, but those chairs are not named in any way.

Answer (score 3):

No such chair exists.

The Hebrew term for a seat may also be used to describe a rôle (the English word “position” has a similar feature): writings referring to people occupying Moses’ seat *might* refer to those who teach as Moses did.