# Why does Eliyahu appear at a brit milah?

Tags: brit-milah, eliyahu-hanavi

There's really not much to add here...

What's the connection between Eliyahu and the Brit Milah? We have a *kiseh shel eliyahu* (Chair of Eliyahu) and we mention his name when the infant is placed on the chair.

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/22265/please-explain-the-idea-of-the-chair-of-elijah-in-synagogue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Explaining the Customs of Bris Milah](https://www.yeshiva.co/midrash/16957) (relevant excerpt):

> WHY IS THERE A CHAIR FOR ELIYAHU?
>
> According to the Midrash, Eliyahu Hanavi attends every bris. Before
>   Eliyahu rose to heaven and assumed the role of an angel, he was the
>   prophet responsible for admonishing the wicked monarchs Achav and
>   Izevel. Eliyahu was a zealot for Hashem’s honor (Melachim 1:19:10, 14)
>   and accused Bnei Yisrael of abrogating Bris Milah. As a response,
>   Hashem decreed that Eliyahu would be present at every bris to see that
>   the Jews indeed fulfill bris milah. Chazal therefore instituted the
>   custom that there should be a seat of honor for Eliyahu at every bris
>   (Pirkei D’Rabbi Eliezer, Chapter 29; Zohar 93a). Eliyahu thus came to
>   be called the "Angel of the Covenant," since he attends and attests to
>   every bris. Therefore, the chair that the baby is placed upon before
>   the bris is referred to as Kisay shel Eliyahu.

Comment: The reference is incomplete.  It's Zohar 1 [Bereshit] 93a.